# How can I get a macro (e.g. for a function parameter) to gracefully expand within a listing?

Tags: listings, verbatim

I try to pass a parameter to code environment (`lstlisting`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\def\parameter{home/Desktop/example_01/}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\parameter
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

but I get `\parameter` in the output and not the directory.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: listings is by design a "verbatim" environment, why use listings here? and if you want to use listings will it always be the complete body in a single macro or do you want to expand arbitrary macros in the body of a listing?

Comment: If you want `\parameter` to get expanded, you can invoke it inside an "escape to LaTeX"; see section 4.14 of the `listings` documentation.

Comment: What style (series, colour, etc.?) should `\parameter` be typeset in? Same as the current style in the listing, at the place where `\parameter` occurs? Or a completely independent style (i.e. italics, no matter where `\parameter` occurs)?

Comment: The parameter is a folder directory. I try to explain what I am trying to do: I am reading the current directory via `pwd` and pass this to the `\parameter`. Then I run the .tex file and get e.g. a plot where I want the current directory to be shown on the bottom of the page... sry, if this sounds confusing, that's why I first created the minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't explain your reasons why you would want to use control sequences within a listing, but I can think of at least one: **maintainability**. That way, if you change the definition of your macro, that change gets reflected everywhere the macro is used within your listings, just like what happens in the "normal text" of your TeX file.

### Simple solution

As David points out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/how-can-i-get-a-macro-e-g-for-a-function-parameter-to-gracefully-expand-withi#comment489894_209635), though, `lstlisting` is an environment within which `\` doesn't have the special meaning it normally has in TeX. Therefore, `\parameter` will not be interpreted as a macro and will simply get printed *verbatim*.

If you want `\parameter` to get expanded within your listing, you have no other choice but to escape to LaTeX. See section 4.14 of the `listings` documentation for more details.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\def\parameter{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=`]
`\parameter`
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

### More advanced solution using `listings` highlighting

The plot thickens if you want the replacement text of your `\parameter` macro to be typeset in the "current listing style", i.e. the style that is used in the listing where your `\parameter` macro occurs. For instance, if `\parameter` occurs within a comment, you may want it to be typeset in comment style (whatever that is); if it occurs within a string, you may want it to be typeset in string style, etc.

One way of doing that is to save the current style in a macro (called `currentStyle@lstparam` below) at the global scope, and invoke that macro in the definition of your `\parameter` control sequence.

See below for an example of this approach applied to a [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) listing.

[image]

Note that the replacement text of `\listparam` (`ns`, here) takes the current style of the listing. Now, if, for instance, you substitute `xs` for `ns` in the definition of `\listparam`, that change gets reflected in each occurrence of `\listparam` in your listing:

[image]

There you go.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% some listings shenanigans to have access to the current listings style
% within an escape to LaTeX
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentStyle@lstparam{}
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\global\let\currentStyle@lstparam\lst@thestyle}
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\global\let\currentStyle@lstparam\lst@thestyle}
\makeatother

% define a character for escaping to LaTeX from within a listing
\lstset{escapechar=`}

% define a placeholder
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listparam{\currentStyle@lstparam ns} %<-- try to change that to `xs'
\makeatother

% set things up for our Haskell example
\lstset{
  language = Haskell,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  commentstyle = \color{ForestGreen},
  stringstyle  = \color{magenta},
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
-- a low-level reimplementation of 'last' (just for exposition purposes)
-- last `\listparam` : the last element of the list '`\listparam`'
last :: [a] -> [a]
last [] = error "List argument `\listparam` is empty, silly!"
last `\listparam` =
  if null (tail `\listparam`) then
    head `\listparam`
  else
    last (tail `\listparam`)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer!
I tried the simple solution, it unfortunately does not work for `\def\parameter{home/Desktop/example_01/}`... it there a possibility to pass the parameter to lstlisting as a usual code sequence?

Comment: for the advanced solution I get an error: `miktex-makemf: The fvmb8r source file could not be found.` .. I can't find `fvmb8r` in the Package Manager.

Comment: @Andy `home/Desktop/example_01/` doesn't work because you need to escape the undescore: `home/Desktop/example\_01/`. I'm not sure what you mean by "pass the parameter to `lstlisting` as a usual code sequence". As for the error you're getting, you should try to update your distribution, if needed.

Comment: @Andy Did an update solve the problem with `fvmb8r`?

Comment: I didn't update yet.. because I would have to escape the underscore anyway, or wouldn't I?