# Use macros within listing

Tags: macros, listings

I would like to use I macro I have defined (including mathematical symbols) within a listing environment. However, the following code prints "\foo{x}" rather than "bar(x)". Is there any way of achieving the latter output?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{$bar(#1)$}

\begin{lstlisting}
\foo{x}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you meant `bar` and not `\bar`?

Comment: Yes, I am. Would it make a difference?

Comment: Well, I just thought you want to achieve the effect of a `\overbar` or something like that.

Comment: Sure. But wouldn't this work exactly the same way?

Comment: Well, do you 'just' want to have an `\overbar` over the `x` or even over the parentheses too?

Comment: I've added an example with an extensible `bar` over the (x)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/how-can-i-get-a-macro-e-g-for-a-function-parameter-to-gracefully-expand-withi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use the `escapechar` option to the listings environment, for example `escapechar=\%` would specify, that any LaTeX code after a `%` character is interpreted as LaTeX and not printed verbatim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{$bar(#1)$}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%]
%\foo{x}%
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will print a true bar over `(x)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}%
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{$\widebar{(#1)}$}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%]
%\foo{x}%
Some other stuff
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: it is advisable to "close" the escaped environment after the macro, e.g. %\foo{x}%. Otherwise, lstlisting's  behaviour, e.g. if it comes to newlines, is different. (Newlines will then be treated as if they were LaTeX code.)

Comment: @Florian: Thanks, I forgot the `%` (answered quite quickly)