# How to use same font-style with escapechar in lstlisting?

Tags: formatting, listings, code

## Original Question

I want to highlight something inside a C++-comment in a code-listing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{light_gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\lstset{ 
breaklines=true
numbers=left,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
frame=single
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++, escapechar=\%]
/**%\textcolor{light_gray}{************************************************}%
 * ... text ...
 *************************************************/  
\end{lstlisting}    
\end{document}
```

Using this code I get the following output:
[image: Original output]

Is there a way to format the grey stars in the same style like the other ones?

---

## Update

Ok, thanks to [Jubobs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs)' answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209644/59838), I was able to create a quick solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{light_gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

% some listings shenanigans to have access to the current listings style
% within an escape to LaTeX
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentStyle@lstparam{}
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\global\let\currentStyle@lstparam\lst@thestyle}
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\global\let\currentStyle@lstparam\lst@thestyle}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
% Usage: \highlightcode{color}{content}
\newcommand{\highlightcode}[2]{\currentStyle@lstparam \textcolor{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true
    numbers=left,
    frame=single
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++, escapechar=\%]
/**%\highlightcode{light_gray}{************************************************}%
 * ... text ...
 *************************************************/  
\end{lstlisting}   
\end{document}
```

The output I get is now:
[image: Updated output]

Looks like `lstlisting` uses another font for default than `\ttfamily`.

I'm OK with that but is there a possibility to use the same font-style here as the first output?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/how-can-i-get-a-macro-e-g-for-a-function-parameter-to-gracefully-expand-withi/209644#209644

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I'm looking for, unfortunately Google didn't find that answer.
I've tested your solution and it seems to work.
I'll update the question as soon as I implemented it completely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was solved in the comments.